# MYSQL Update AND SUM

Tags: mysql, select, sql-update, sum, inner-join

i am try to do somethink like this

```
UPDATE BA C
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT SUM(`Amount`) AS `LSC`,`To` FROM `Trans`
) A ON C.`UserID` = A.`To`

INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT SUM(`Amount`) AS `LSC`,`From` FROM `Trans`
) B ON C.`UserID` = B.`From`

SET `Bal` = A.`LSC` - B.`LSC`;
```

and this is not workink :\ 
when i just do 1 inner join and run the query twice once to A and second to be it work but i want to do it in one query ...

```
UPDATE BA C
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT SUM(`Amount`) AS `LSC`,`To` FROM `Trans`
) A ON C.`UserID` = A.`To`

SET `Bal` = A.`LSC`; // Work
```

Comment: move both the `set` after the joins.

Comment: Use GROUP BY when using aggregate functions as SUM.